# How to use Auth 1.0 API Shopee Open Platform

Tags: laravel

I have problem of accessing API auth Shopee, error messages on postman is "Invalid token".

From guide https://open.shopee.com/documents?module=63&type=2&id=53
How to generate token, please help me

Comment: I visited the link, it asks to send id, token & redirect url, use the verification token provided by them to you.

Comment: I has try to generate token, but its token not working. From this API i get msg "Invalid token"